# 301 redirects in Grails

Tags: grails, seo, http-status-code-301

I'm currently doing my Grails 301 URL-redirects using the following quite cumbersome "servlet style" method:

```
def action = {
  ...
  if (shouldRedirect) {
    response.status = 301
    response.setHeader("Location", "http://url/to/redirect/to.html")
    render("")
    return false
  }
  ...
}
```

**Is there any cleaner and more compact Groovy/Grails'y way to perform a 301 redirect?**

Please note that I'm talking about 301 redirect, not the standard 302 redirects which can be achieved using the standard Grails `redirect(...)` mechanism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's now possible to use `redirect` and specify the `permanent` parameter as `true` as described [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html). For example:

```
redirect(url: "http://url/to/redirect/to.html", permanent: true)
```

Comment: Is it better to set all controller's redirects to status 301, as far as SEO is concerned, or should one leave them as 302 ?

Comment: @Euoliix If a redirect is really permanent, then you should use 301. If Google sees 302 then supposedly it will check the URL again later.

Answer (score 2):

The [`redirect`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) mechanism in Grails currently supports a `permanent` parameter:

> `permanent` (optional) - If true the redirect will be issued with a 301 HTTP status code (permanently moved), otherwise a 302 HTTP status code will be issued

This should adequately solve your problem, and in a very Grails-y way.